# SiteEdit 2009 SP2 - Error accessing to SiteEdit

Tags: 2009, siteedit

I configured SiteEdit in our system (Tridion 2009 SP1).

When a user is trying to access to the system we get the following error:

```
Unable to Initialize TDSE object.
Access is denied for the user .

Error Code:
0x80040302 (-2147220734)

Call stack:
SystemBLST.GetUserContext
SystemBLST.IBLSecurityST_GetUserContext
TDSE.Initialize
```

Someone has seen this error before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the SiteEdit Application Pool is set to run as "Network Service" and that "Network Service" is configured as a valid impersonator.

At the very least, the application pools for Tridion and for SiteEdit should run under the same user account. If you're using LDAP authentication then the whole thing gets a bit more complicated, but it's the same principles (just more windows-based security settings to change, like File System access permissions).